# How to replace the blank cells in r dataframe?

Tags: r

i have on data with columns as shown below..

```
empid age  Dept     Marital status
100   23   IT             yes
101   24    Finance      
102   26    IT           
103    25    IT           yes
```

how to replace the  blank cells in marital status column with "NO"????

Comment: Those are NOT "cells" at least if this is an R object which I rather doubt. But assuming they are, then they are values in a vector in a dataframe.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the 'Marital Status' column is `character` class, we can get a logical vector by checking whether the values in 'Marital status' is equal to blank (`df1[,'Marital status']=='']`), use that index to assign the elements to 'NO'.

```
df1[,'Marital status'][df1[,'Marital status']==''] <- 'NO'
```

---

If we are using `data.table` (from @Henk's comments), we convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), based on the logical index, we assign 'NO' to the 'Marital status' column.  As the column name includes multiple words, we can use backtick to wrap to create the logical index.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[`Marital status` =='', 'Marital status' := 'NO']
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(empid = 100:103, age = c(23L, 24L, 26L, 25L), 
Dept = c("IT", "Finance", "IT", "IT"), `Marital status` = c("yes", 
"", "", "yes")), .Names = c("empid", "age", "Dept", "Marital status"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: the solution became more involved because the field name contains a space. when you rename to "marital.status" you can just :
 df1[marital.status == "", marital.status := "no"] (in data.table)